# Can you combine two existing stations in openTTD?

Tags: openttd

I recently started a new openTTD game, and forgot to hit `ctrl` while putting down my first airport near a bus station. I want the passenger service of both to merge together, but I'd rather not write off the airport's cost as a loss.

Is this possible?

Comment: wouldn't it be cheaper to rebuild the bus station? :)

Comment: @yx. I'm guessing he's probably attached some bus services to the bus stop already

Comment: You could `ctrl` that? Good to know. :)

Comment: @Yi Jiang, correct - and I really don't want to lose 1200+ passengers waiting for transportation. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you cannot merge two stations after they are built. You can however rebuild one of them and then join them back in with the other station.

Answer (score 2):

As a possible workaround, you could build a second bus station linked to the airport and provide a bus service that transfers passengers from the first bus station to the airport.  That's what I'd do, anyway.